# How can I make cards components all the same size in React?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am working with styling all my components and the only thing I can't make it is all cards the same size. what should I add to my styling to fix it? I used display grid for the cards and display flex insede of card, also I styled image but it still some of them are different size

[image]

Here is my code ItemsComponent.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles/ItemComponent.css";

function ItemsComponent() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [filterItems, setFilterItems] = useState("");

  // Fetching Data
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchedData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products`);
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log("Data", data);
        setItems(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    fetchedData();
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <main>
        <div className="search">
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="search-items">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Search..."
                onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
              />
              <button className="btn-light btn-search">Search</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div className="categories">
          <button
            className="btn-dark category"
            onClick={() => setFilterItems("")}
          >
            All
          </button>
          <button
            className="btn-dark category"
            onClick={() => setFilterItems("men's clothing")}
          >
            Men's Clothing
          </button>
          <button
            className="btn-dark category"
            onClick={() => setFilterItems("women's clothing")}
          >
            Women's Closing
          </button>
          <button
            className="btn-dark category"
            onClick={() => setFilterItems("jewelery")}
          >
            Jewelry
          </button>
          <button
            className="btn-dark category"
            onClick={() => setFilterItems("electronics")}
          >
            Electronics
          </button>
        </div>
      </main>
      <div className="grid-container">
        {Array.from(items)
          .filter((item) => !filterItems || item.category === filterItems)
          .filter(
            (value) =>
              !search ||
              value.title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
          )
          .map((item) => (
            <div key={item.id} className="item-container">
              <div className="card">
                <h3 className="title">{item.title}</h3>
                <img src={item.image} alt={item.title} />
                <h5 className="price">£ {item.price}</h5>
                <button className="btn-dark btn-buy">
                  <Link to={`/${item.id}`} className="btn-link">
                    Buy Now
                  </Link>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default ItemsComponent;
```

And here css styling:

```
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px 0 auto auto;
}

/* Categories Style */
.categories {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 30px;
}

.category {
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.category:hover {
  background-color: var(--btn-light-color);
  color: var(--primary-dark-color);
  transition: 0.7;
}

/* Creating Item Card */
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-row: 1rem;
  gap: 2rem;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 15rem auto;
}

.item-container {
}

.card {
  margin: 1rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(88 88 88 /20%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 1em 1em 1.5em;
  border-radius: 1px solid transparent;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.price {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* style doesn't apply */
.btn-buy a .btn-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--btn-light-color);
}

.btn-buy:hover {
  background-color: var(--secondary-dark-color);
  transition: 0.7;
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

/* Style Search Bar */

.search {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

input {
  width: 500px;
  height: 30px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 7px;
  border: 1px solid var(--primary-dark-color);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 30px 20px;
}

input:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(88 88 88 /20%);
}

.btn-search {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.btn-search:hover {
  background-color: var(--secondary-dark-color);
  color: var(--primary-color);
  transition: 0.7;
}

/* =======Media Queries (Tablets)========= */
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 1.2rem;
  }

  input {
    width: 450px;
  }

  .btn-search {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
}

/* ==========Media Queries (Mobies) ===========*/
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    gap: 1rem;
  }

  input {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
```

Thank you in advince.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey @zulfiya make change in css-

```
.title {
  text-align: center;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  margin: 30px 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

This is stop overflowing of text from the div.. Hope it will solve your problem, if you still facing issue just lemme know. I will help you.
Thanks

Comment: The problem with that solution is that it will crop the content. Extending the box should be a better solution.

Comment: Then fix the height of div... Thanks

Comment: Thank you, I added height property to card and it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `align-items: stretch` to your `grid-container` div.
A more flexible solution than manually setting the height if you can't guess the height of the card contents.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a new file and use props to pass data. There in that `jsx` you can define the height of the image using CSS, after that, all images will be of the same size.

Comment: Why wouldnt css styling work?

Comment: Why should he make a new component just to style them?

Comment: Who knows how many products he will add, this would be better.

Comment: This is fetched data from public api and there is an array with 20 elements.

Comment: It's still a loop and it would be the same loop even if he had made a component out of it. Components are good but not because of the amount of items, its good mainly to separate logic, styling etc from other components. For example I could see how every item could use their own state management for future functionality and it would be easier to maintain if the items were their own component.